# How can I pull data from MYSQL based on Longitude, Latitude and radius in PHP PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo, latitude-longitude

I'm developing an application where it needs to show results based on the person longitude, latitude and user selected radius, then return the result in `Json` array format `json_encode();`

I have 3 files in my project as **sdbconnection.php**, **manipulate.php** and **pull.php**. Below I have explained how exactly each file works.

**sdbconnection.php** is my server and database connection.

```
//MySQL Database Connection Credential
class connection {
    public static $host = "XXXXX";
    public static $user = "XXXXXXX";
    public static $password = "XXXXXXX";
    public static $database = "XXXXXXX";
    public static $port = "XXXXX";
}
```

**manipulate.php** is how I exccute my SQL query and return the result. I have tried to figure out how to send requests from [google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3), but i believe that I'm missing something since they are not using the **PDO** connection.

```
public function pullResults($longitude, $latitude, $radius){
    $retunValue = array();
    $sql = "SELECT title, latitude, longitude, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(:lat) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(:lng) ) + sin( radians(:lat) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM posts HAVING distance < :radius ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20";

    $result = $this->connection->query($sql);
        if ($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)) {
            $row =  $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            if (!empty($row)) {
                $retunValue = $row;
            }
        }

    return $retunValue;
}
```

**pull.php** is where users request to execute their respond and when i try it in browser, I get **Blank** page.

```
//Database Connection and Query Manipulation.
require("handles/sdbconnection.php");
require("handles/manipulate.php");

// Get parameters from URL
$latitude = $_GET["latitude"];
$longitude= $_GET["longitude"];
$radius = $_GET["radius"];
$category = htmlentities($_GET["category"]);

//Connect to database
$databaseAccess = new manipulate();
$databaseAccess->openConnection();

//Get the Result
$databaseAccess->pullResults($longitude, $latitude, $radius);

//Close Connection After Data Pulled
$databaseAccess->closeConnection();
```

Also, if you see, I'm trying to be more specific in my MYSQL query by retrieving data by providing multiple categories (`$category = htmlentities($_GET["category"]);`), I really appreciate if you show me how to do that as well.

**Procedure:**
[image]

Comment: Sketch out the topology -- client, web server, etc.  You may be asking to do something impossible, and need to rethink the dataflow.

Comment: So what are you actually asking about here – the “blank page” that for some reason baffles you, or how to do such a search in general? _Both_ are topics that can be researched quite well, here on SO as well as on the rest of the net.

Comment: Impressive!  Is Radius relevant to your question?

Comment: @CBroe I can't, cause they are not explained in PDO connectivity to MYSQL, I believe my problem is either the query or the way PDO works

Comment: @RickJames Yes, the radius is the important factor, is what confuse me.

Comment: Where do you want to start? Your `pullResults` function receives the lat/lng/radius as parameters, but it does not pass them into the SQL query itself, the query seems to be using `mysqli` instead of/mixed with PDO, the category is completely ignored, you're not using the return value of `pullResults()`, *and* you're seemingly not outputting *anything* to the browser...

Comment: @DCoder Can you please show me how to do it the correct way?

Comment: `$latitude = $_GET["latitude"];` implies that the latitude comes in the url on the blue arrow.

Comment: @RickJames yes that is correct, The platform is iOS and I sending HTTP  from there.

Comment: Ah...  `:lat` is one of your questions. -- Pick either PDO or mysqli; then we can discuss how to do substitutions.

Comment: Mysqli@RickJames but i appreciate if you show me PDO as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"PDO" and "mysqli_*" are two separate APIs.  Do not mix them.

`pullResults` has `return $retunValue;`, yet the call to it throws away the return value.

```
$string = json_encode($retunValue);
```

will product a string, that you can `echo` into the result.

Is the "platform" expecting HTML output?  Or just JSON text?  If the latter, you need this as the *first* statement that emits output:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Bottom line:  This might be all you need:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($retunValue);
```

(I have not checked for other issues.)

Comment: Just Plain JSON as i mention in the question.